# ¿Cómo relacionar un campo tipo array a una colección usando Mongodb y Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, php7, laravel-8

Tengo un Modelo llamado `Libros` y en esa colección tengo un campo tipo array el en cual que guarda los `_ids` por ejemplo ese campo puede guardar un array asi:

```
[ '001',
  '002'
]
```

de los Autores  quisiera obtener los datos de los autores al consultar un libro.

En mi Modelo Libros tengo la siguiente relación:

```
public function autores()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Autor::class);
}
```

En mi Controller de Libros tengo el siguiente query para obtener los libros con sus autores:

```
Libros::with(['autores' => function($query){
                $query->select('*');            
        }]);
```

El modelo Autor lo tengo la siguiente manera:

```
public function libros()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Libros::class);
    }
```

pero autores lo regresa vacío, podrían ayudarme por favor ?

Comment: Buen día, ¿Puedes mostrar como tienes el modelo de `Autor`? Tal vez te hace falta crear la relación ahí. [Lectura recomendada](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Comment: @HeytalePazguato perdón edote la pregunta, tienes razon faltaba mas información